Check if value exist in firebase realtime database React js
I have create a Realtime database below

I just want a code to check if the inputed email exist in the database. An alert should be shown to the user.
My code so far though not working thanks
export default function Login() {
  
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {   
    const db = getDatabase(app);
    const dbRef = ref(db, "nature/");
    const query = dbRef.orderByChild('email').equalTo('email');
    query.once('value', function(snapshot) {          
      if (snapshot.exists()) {
        alert("login")     
      } else { 
        alert("notloged")     
      }
    });      
  };

  return (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div>
          <label>Email:</label>
          <input
            type="email"
            value={email}
            onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
            required
          />
        </div>
       
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
      </form>
    );
   }


I'm immediately wondering if the user had permission to read the data. Did you check the JavaScript console for any (relevant) errors?

If I take your code and put it into a shell here, it works: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rtdb-compat-query

I am getting a response dbRef.orderByChild is not a function

You're mixing the (newer) modular API with the (older) namespaces API syntax. While both syntaxes are still valid, you can't mix and match them.
The equivalent of dbRef.orderByChild('email').equalTo('email') in the modular syntax would be:
const qry = query(dbRef, orderByChild('email'), equalTo('email')];
get(qry).then((snapshot) => {
   ...
})

That are based on the documentation on reading a value once and filtering data, so I recommend keeping these and the upgrade guide handy.

It worked, thanks

Good to hear @drevanet. --- Also see What should I do when someone answers my question?
